# Loss of Appetite since exercise

Tags: cardio

I have increased cardio by minimal amount and feel less hungry ....

This is good for cutting out snacks but I feel as if I'm forcing myself to eat full breakfast, medium lunch, light dinner.

Any tips on how to get normal appetite for required food intake?

Comment: Be more active? Nothing brings back appetite more than hunger :)

Comment: Yes this happened when I started being active. Of course I am gradually adding more cardio, ie jogging and jump rope ....

Comment: Do you feel weak, as if you're not getting enough fuel for the exercise? And when do you exercise? Is it near your mealtimes?

Comment: @SeanDuggan I feel fine when I exercise. If I'm hungry I drink 1% milk and eat spoon of peanut butter. And the exercise is 5pm to about 5:45pm ... dinner around 7pm

Comment: By the by, if you do find that you're not consuming enough calories, http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/4214/8039 may help you find ways to do so.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Well I hope it never comes down to me not eating enough .... that's kind of scary ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's entirely possible that this is [perfectly normal](http://www.livestrong.com/article/405012-exercise-loss-of-appetite/). Exercise, in particular cardio, stimulates certain hormones and suppresses others:

> A one-hour aerobic exercise session helps reduce ghrelin levels and increase Peptide YY levels, decreasing your appetite when you are finished, according to a 2008 study published in the "American Journal of Physiology."

Generally, this loss of appetite recedes within an hour or so of your workout. In fact, a common problem among people working out is that, when the hormone levels reassert themselves, they can do so with a vengeance, resulting in eating more than you had intended as your body tries to refuel itself. If it's a more longterm problem, particularly if you're finding yourself getting woozy from low blood sugar and if you're doing an excessive amount of exercise, then you need to take it more seriously, finding some easy-to-eat foods that you can eat an hour or two after exercise to ensure your caloric intake.

As with many things diet-related, one of your best first steps is to start writing down what you eat. That will give you an idea as to whether you're still getting in the 1200 calories (1000 for women) that the FDA recommends as a minimum.

Under the heading of anecdote, I've personally found that I seem to eat less overall since I've started running three times a week. I just don't feel like I need as much food. However, that's more from the perspective of snacking, and smaller portions, than not feeling like eating all day.

Comment: I like the idea of writing down food-intake